Double ?? mark with dynamic variablename?.variable
Can someone please explain the below code. Here, name ?? stands for nullable types if its null then what is data?.name?
string name = req.Query["name"];

dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
name ??= data?.name;


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

"Here, name ?? stands for nullable types" - no, it's the null-coalescing operator, and ??= is the null-coalescing assignment operator. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Whereas ?. is the null-conditional operator, as jonrsharpe's comment linked to.

I have formatted your question for clarity and general best practices. Please ensure you follow the same style in your future questions.

Also, please remember to upvote/accept answers that you think are useful and respond to your question.

name ??= data?.name; is notionally equivalent to name = (name == null ? (data == null ? null : data.name) : name);, if that helps ;) - in English "if name is null and data is not null, set name to data.name"

The ??= is the null-coalescing assignment operator.
It is a version of the null-coalescing operator ?? that can be used to assign a value to a variable, but only if the value to be assigned is not null. I.e., the variable will be overwritten only if the value to assign is not null:
someVariable ??= someValue

here someVariable will be assigned someValue only if someValue is not null.
It is the same as doing:
someVariable = someVariable ?? someValue

Instead, the ?. operator is simply the null-conditional operator.
It's used to access a variable value, typically the property of an object that may be null. If you access a property of an object that is null, you will get a NullReferenceException. Instead, by using this operator, the exception can be avoided and simply null is returned:
someVariable = someObject?.someProperty

Here someVariable will be assigned the value of someProperty if someObject is not null (it has a value), or null otherwise.
So, for your example:
string name = req.Query["name"];

here, you define the variable name and a value (req.Query["name"]) is set for it. I imagine that this value may or may not be null.
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody)

because the dynamic type is used here, you won't know either the type of data nor whether data is null or not.
Finally,
name ??= data?.name;

Here you basically say, _keep the same value that name had so far, or override its value with the value of data.name but only if data is not null and data.name is not null.
Note that if the initial value of name was null, you may still end up with a null value of name at the end of this code.

Might also be worth a mention as to whether data?.name is evaluated at all if name is not null
